# Ordering left outer join using right table with fallback

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got two tables:

- Table1 - Id, created_at
- Table2, Id, table1_id, created_at

I want to include all Table1 rows with a join that fetches the latest Table2 record (if any, there may not be any table2 records) and used the created_at on Table2 to order the result. If there is not a Table2 record I'd like to be able to use the created_at in Table1 for that record's ordering.

Example:

```
Table 1 (id, created_at)  
1, 100  
2, 200  
3, 300  
4, 400  

Table 2 (id, table1_id, created_at)  
1, 1, 500  
2, 1, 450  
3, 2, 350
```

And the query would give the result (t1.id, t1.created_at, t2.id, t2.created_at)

```
1, 100, 1, 500  
4, 400, --, --  
2, 200, 2, 350  
3, 300, --, --
```

I'm using Postgresql. What would the best query/method to accomplish this?

Comment: either i understand your question, or simple left joing: Select * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1_id = table1.id

Comment: It needs to be ordered by table2.created_at falling back to using table1.created_at if that any row that does not have an associated table2 (but only for those rows, not all the results)You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)
i.e that query does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've come up with a query that appears to work:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (
    t2.t1_id = t1.id
    AND 
    t2.id = (SELECT tt2.id FROM table2 tt2 WHERE tt2.t1_id = t1.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
) ORDER BY COALESCE(f2.created_at, f1.created_at) DESC;
```

Not sure if this is the best or most efficient way of doing this so I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.id, t1.created_at, t2.id, t2.created_at
from
    table1 t1 
    left outer join (
        select id, max(created_at) created_at
        from table2
        group by id
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by coalesce(f2.created_at, f1.created_at) desc;
```

Comment: Assuming I also want to retrieve more rows from t2 then is it safe or unsafe to assume that the values would be correct for the latest record in t2 or would only the created_at be correct?

Comment: You want more rows or more columns? For both the query would be different.

Comment: Sorry, meant more columns. Won't let me edit my comment now but it should of been:
Assuming I also want to retrieve more columns from t2 then is it safe or unsafe to assume that the values would be correct for the latest record in t2 or would only the created_at be correct?